# Сравнение строк через тернарный оператор в Ruby

Tags: ruby

Пробую учить Ruby. Есть задача: создать переменные "First" и "Second", присвоить им имена. С помощью тернарного оператора вывести значение бОльшей из переменных.

```
first_person = 'Peter'
second_person = 'Andrue'
first_person>second_person ? puts first_person: puts second_person
```

Попробовал так, выдаёт:

> "Runtime error:\nERRORCODE: 1 \n/edx/app/graders-ruby101/var/Program0a6969f900334c3d060800c2607d88f0_5562743076668297_255739.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected label, expecting `do' or '{' or '('\n...ond_person ? puts first_person: puts second_person\n...                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n"

Comment: Что означает "Не работает"? Ничего не выводит? Выводит, но не то?

Comment: Выводить, кстати, нужно переменную, а не совсем другую строку.

Comment: first_person = 'Peter'
second_person = 'Andrue'
first_person>second_person?puts first_person: second_person  попробовал и так, выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Фраза "выдаёт ошибку" без текста ошибки бесполезна.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        2: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
SyntaxError ((irb):3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting do or '{' or '(')
first_person>second_person?puts first_person: puts second_pe...
                           ^~~~
(irb):3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting do or '{' or '('
...irst_person: puts second_person
...                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
irb(main):004:0>

Comment: ну синтаксис неправильный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробелы и скобки:

```
first_person > second_person ? (puts first_person) : (puts second_person)
```

Comment: Благодарю вас, все сработало. И прошу прощения за, может быть, банальные вопросы, но вокруг просто некому объяснить.